# What are some chaotic long lasting initial conditions for the three-body problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, chaos-theory, three-body-problem

I have been trying to find some good long lasting chaotic trajectories for the three-body problem, but it seems to be very hard to find.

All I find on the internet is a lot of periodic solutions for the three body problem and some short lasting chaotic trajectories.
What I am specifically looking for is a set of initial conditions where the chaotic trajectories last for at least something like 200 seconds and at best 1000 seconds (something between 200-1000 seconds). It is also useful if the initial conditions aren't too complicated   (like a 15 long decimal digit number), but instead is a simple number (like 1, -1.5, 0.5,...).

I have tried to brute force it by trying myself some somewhat random initial conditions, but one of the three bodies always seems to knock off one of the other bodies leaving only two bodies.

Comment: Congratulations, you have discovered a general feature of gravitating n-particle systems: they are not stable and disintegrate. I have found statements that in the three body the chaotic states always disintegrate. I can't give you a reference to a proof, though. It sounds likely enough because for chaos two of the bodies have to come arbitrarily close (otherwise we won't get bifurcations, I believe). I might be wrong.

Comment: Asking for a specific range of time for the chaotic trajectories doesn't make much sense.  You could just scale up the initial coordinates, velocities, or masses to fine-tune the time before a body is ejected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. Test if you can reproduce one of the unstable periodic solutions you find in the literature;
2. Take a point on this periodic solution and modify it ever so slightly — that should make the orbit shorter lasting;
3. Now gradually increase the change in the initial condition until the corresponding orbit has the desired length duration.

And you can at the same time make an effort to find 'rounder' numbers, but this probably won't be fun.

Answer (score 0):

The sun, earth, moon system is chaotic, it's just chaotic over a fairly small range, so the overall shape is long lasting.  Perturbations in the smaller bodies don't dramatically affect the motion of the larger bodies.

Increase the relative mass the smaller objects and the range of possible orbits increases.  A system where all three bodies have the same mass should diverge pretty rapidly.

I would think you should be able to test a few values for the relative masses of the three objects and find one where the divergence happens on the scale you're looking for.